# Is there a log of errors produced during an upgrade?

Tags: 13.04, upgrade

At the end of an upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04, I received an error message something to this effect:

```
some programs could not be installed. You will have to reinstall them after reboot.
```

My question: Is there a log produced during the upgrade that I could see to tell me what these programs that failed installation were?

**UPDATE:**

```
$ ls -al /var/log/dist-upgrade
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 19  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 Oct 23 08:12 ..
$
```

sigh

Comment: Have a look at `/var/log/dist-upgrade/` folder.

Comment: munged my dir listing.  deleting, will add to main question